# Laravel database configuration for local and remote environment

Tags: php, git, laravel

I just have a database issue on my project/app/config/database.php. I want to my application can change its database when detecting its database environment. For example, if application is develop in local database, the database setting are all local parameter. If it detect that the database is on the remote server, it changes into remote database settings.

```
        'mysql' => array(
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => $_ENV['DB_HOST'],
        'database'  => $_ENV['DB_NAME'],
        'username'  => $_ENV['DB_USER'],
        'password'  => $_ENV['DB_PASSWORD'],
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => 'laravel_',

    ),
```

Comment: Use [Environment configuration](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/configuration)

Comment: if (App::environment('local'))
{
    // The environment is local
}

if (App::environment('local', 'staging'))
{
    // The environment is either local OR staging...
}

Comment: which laravel version are you using?

Comment: In Laravel 5 you store all environment-specific config values in `.env` file in root folder of your app. This file should have different values on local and production machines. Example of its syntax is in `.env.example`.

Comment: @nozzleman  Laravel 4.2

Answer (score 1):

I've solved the problem, however, not by adding local folder in to config folder as the [document](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/configuration) said. 
I check the article [Working with Configuration in Laravel 4](http://culttt.com/2014/04/07/working-configuration-laravel-4/), it is useful if you use .env.local.php to protect you local database configuration.